# Is there a usual, widely used word (a noun) in English that can mean a nice/cute/etc cat and a nice/cute/etc guy as well (internet slang, maybe)?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

In my language I have a phrase/wordplay about a guy surrounded by cats:

> "I see just a bunch of _____"

I need a hypernym that is a word for the cute cats and the cute guy, in a playful way. In my language it's just a diminutive of a word for cat.

Comment: I need a noun. In my language I have a phrase about a guy surrounded by cats, "I see just a bunch of (cats? Kittens? It's a wordplay, I need a word that will work for the guy too, something with a few meanings, in my language it's just a diminutive of a word for cat)".

Comment: @Cascabel It's good, but the matter comes from my language, where (idk why) nobody uses dogs to say someone's cute, but you can use the same word for an adorable cat or an adorable human. And then there was created the situation with a pile of cats, so it's almost necessary to find exactly a cat word in order not to destroy the original idea.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98427/discussion-on-question-by-user357995-is-there-a-usual-widely-used-word-a-noun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***pussycat***

> humorous: someone who is surprisingly gentle:

[-Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pussycat)

I guess you could say..

> I just see a bunch of *pussycats*.

Comment: I've seen it in the dictionary, but it wasn't exactly what I needed. Anyway, a view from a native speaker is always useful. Thank you one more time x).

Comment: I don't think I can make it more clear. And I think if there was a word I need I would already find it. I did my best, and you said there's little chances that it exists. I'd like to close the topic, I just don't fully understand how it all works here.

Comment: Note that "pussycat" is also applied to women: https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/tomjones/whatsnewpussycat.html

Comment: @HotLicks That is true. In this case however, and as I often say, maybe it is a cross-cultural difficulty, not just a language difficulty. The best we can hope for in these circumstances is an approximation.

Comment: Once upon a time being a "cool cat" was where it was at. Cara de ángel, uñas de gato. "No matter how much cats fight, there always seem to be plenty of kittens." Hey would you look at that: sometimes cats really do grow into kittens! Now there's a cat who can purr his way out of anything. Aquí hay gato encerrado.

Comment: Amazing are there different mean for pussy cat and pussycat?

Answer (score 1):

**Darlings**

I just see a bunch of darlings.  ie, darling cats, darling guys.

If that’s what you are asking?

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/darlings

Answer (score 1):

I would say "cuties"! If they are all cute, then they are cuties regardless of their species.

Comment: yes I think so but he is looking for other way